# detect if user select or typed new value in datalist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-datalist

I'm stuck to detect if user select or typed new value.

Here I have separate datalist component:

```
 //DataList component

  adresses=[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "address": "address 1",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "address": "address 2",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "address": "address 3",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "address": "address 4",
  }
]


<input
  type="text"
  list="data-list"
  className={classname}
  onChange={onchange}
  placeholder={placeholder}
/>
<datalist id="data-list">
  {adresses.map((item, idx) => {
    const { id, address } = item
    return <option key={idx} data-value={id} value={address} />
})}
</datalist>
```

Than I'm calling that component and passing props to it:

```
<DataList
  classname="event_time-inputs datasets"
  onchange={e => this.onChooseAddress(e)}
  adresses={this.state.adresses}
  placeholder={"Type or select address"}
/>
```

OnChange function:

```
 onChooseAddress(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
```

if user select from options I need to somehow pass "data-value" from options. I'm new in react, please understand me for silly questions.

Comment: I think the issue is with the onChange event , Because onChange event should be binded with the value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect when a user has selected an option from a datalist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535306/how-can-i-detect-when-a-user-has-selected-an-option-from-a-datalist)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onClick` on the `<Option />` Component, pass `idx` as an argument and use that later:

```js
onChooseAddress(i) {
  console.log(adresses[i].id)
  console.log(adresses[i].address)
}

return <option key={idx} data-value={id} value={address} onClick={() =>{this.onChooseAddress(idx)}} />
```

Comment: I think you can't add to options any event listeners