# How can I detect when a user has selected an option from a datalist?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to detect when a user has selected an option from the dropdown box on an `input` element linked to a datalist so that I may use that action to trigger another.

For some reason, clicking on the datalist dropdown box does **not** fire a `click` event. So using that is totally out of the question.

Using the `change` event doesn't work for two reasons. Chrome's `change` event is pretty nice, it will fire when someone selects an option, however, in Firefox the event is not fired until the `input` has lost focus. You may think that you could at least use the `change` event for Chrome, but alas, there is another major issue—if you type in the full text of what you're selecting and then click an option, the change event is never fired, because nothing changed :(

Finally, we come to the very ugly but seemingly only option: comparing the current value of the `input` element to the options in the datalist with an `input` event. This has many issues.

1. It doesn't work if one option is a prefix of another (e.g. `foo`, `foobar`). The code will run prematurely if the user types `foo` before selecting `foobar`.
2. Assuming none of your options are prefixes of each other, your code will still run if the user types out the whole text of something in the datalist, as opposed to waiting for them to select it.
3. It has to loop through every single option in the datalist every time you 
   type a character.

You could try to mitigate these issues using `setTimeout` to detect when someone has stopped typing, but that still wouldn't be able to achieve the desired behaviour.

I can't believe there's not a simple event that deals with this, but I know there **must** be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there **is** a way! Our hero is the [Invisible Separator](https://unicode-table.com/en/2063/) (U+2063). It is a character that adds no visible effect to a string, it merely exists. Copy and paste this `f⁣oo` and check its length. You will see it equals 4!

We can append this character to the end of every option in the datalist. Then we can set up a listener for an `input` event, and check if the value of the `input` element ends in U+2063. If it does, you know the user has selected an option. You then should change the value of the `input` element to get rid of the U+2063 (unless the selection is going to trigger something that resets the value anyway).

This overcomes every issue you've stated because the user can't actually type in anything that matches something in the datalist, an option must be selected for anything to happen.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
    if (this.value.slice(-1) === '\u2063') {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
        let div = document.querySelector('div');
        div.textContent = `you selected: ${this.value}`
        div.classList.toggle('red'); //so you can see when this is called even if the text doesn't change
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
}

div {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input list='test'>
<datalist id='test'> 
    <option>foo&#8291;</option>
    <option>bar&#8291;</option>
    <option>foobar&#8291;</option>
</datalist>
<div></div>
```